# Adding fulfilment code to make a cart for order bot. gives me undefined on quantity parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, chat, chatbot, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

> the function below prints the item and in what quantity that has been ordered

```
function confirmitem(agent){
    const item = agent.getContext('item'),
    Food = item.parameters.Food, 
    quantity = item.parameters.quantity;
    agent.add('Confirming '+Food+' in a quantity of '+quantity);
}
```

> below is the output context

```
"outputContexts": [{
    "name": "projects/simple-dialog-wtckcj/agent/sessions/1a459958-2249-5973-9561-5418940b0b22/contexts/item",
    "lifespanCount": 4,
    "parameters": {
        "Food": "matooke",
        "Food.original": "matooke",
        "quantity": {
            "number.original": "1",
            "number": 1
        },
        "quantity.original": "1"
    }
},
{
"name": "projects/simple-dialog-wtckcj/agent/sessions/1a459958-2249-5973-9561-5418940b0b22/contexts/itemconfirm",
"lifespanCount": 4,
"parameters": {
    "quantity": {
        "number": 1,
        "number.original": "1"
    },
    "quantity.original": "1",
    "Food": "matooke",
    "Food.original": "matooke"
}
}
]
```

> the actual output is
>   'Confirming matooke in a quantity of [object Object]'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detecting an undefined object property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27509/detecting-an-undefined-object-property)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `item.parameters.quantity` is an object with a value of

```
    {
        "number.original": "1",
        "number": 1
    },
```

When you try to print this, the normal way to print the object is just with "[object Object]", as you've noticed.

You probably want to access the "number" field inside this object with something like `item.parmeters.quantity.number`. If you wanted to access the "original" value, which is exactly what the user said, you may need to use something like `item.parameters["quantity.original"]`. You would need to use this indexing method because "quantity.original" contains a period.